# Accessing both 'this' variables in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript, this

In TypeScript, if you define a function using `() => {...}`, the `this` variable will refer to the instance of the surrounding class. But if you use `function () {...}`, the `this` variable will have its old JavaScript interpretataion.

Is there any way to access both of these `this` variables within a TypeScript function?

I occasionally need this when using JQuery in TypeScript:

```
class X {
    private v : string;
    constructor() {
        $('.xyz').on('change', function() {
            this.v = $(this).prop('value'); // Two different this's
        })
    }
 }
```

In the central line in the code, the first `this` should refer to the class X object, whereas the second `this` should refer to the JQuery object that triggered the event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `change` event handler `this` will refer to the `.xyz` element that raised the event only. If you want a reference to the containing `X` class then you need to store a variable holding that reference, like this:

```
class X {
    private v : string;
    constructor() {
        var _x = this;
        $('.xyz').on('change', function() {
            _x.v = $(this).prop('value'); 
        })
    }
 }
```